# Error: Expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<' token - Function Declaration

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

code is:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iterator>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <new>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

using std::vector;

    #include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
    #include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>
    #include <boost/numeric/ublas/operation.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp>

    using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;

    boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> A_MATRIX(A_MATRIX_ROWS,A_MATRIX_COLUMNS);
    boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> Y_MATRIX(A_MATRIX_ROWS,1);


    vector <double> GPSR_BB(boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> &f_Y_MATRIX,boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> &f_A_MATRIX,int f_tau,int f_tolA){

vector<double> objective(2);

//sth inside function

return objective;

    }

    int main(){
        vector<double> objectives(maxiter+2);
        objectives=GPSR_BB(Y_MATRIX,A_MATRIX,tau,tolA);
        return 0;
    }
```

in line

```
vector <double> GPSR_BB(boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> &f_Y_MATRIX,boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> &f_A_MATRIX,int f_tau,int f_tolA){
```

I receive this error

> error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘<’
>   token function

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

EDIT: I edited the code, and did everything you told me. I thank all of the help, but error still remains. I guess, the problem is because of matrix data type, from boost library, which I have to pass to function.

Any more suggestions?

Comment: I don't see an `#include <vector>` or `using std::vector` anywhere.  The fix may be as simple as adding the missing include, and either typing `std::vector` where you have `vector` now, or adding `using std::vector` after `#include <vector>`.  (I think most here would lean against the `using` statement...)

Comment: as @JoeZ said and if this don't work just put more information about the error and which line has that error

Comment: Is that your full code?

Comment: @JoeZ I'd wager it's supposed to be `boost::numeric::ublas::vector` and not `std::vector`. Just one more proof that `using namespace` is a bad idea.

Comment: I had both #include <vector> or using std::vector, but I forgot to write. Problem is about function definition I guess.

Comment: I also added boost::numeric::ublas::vector instead of std::vector, which gives another error.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure this is the problem, but you haven't included vector.h or declared 'using namespace std' so vector may be undefined in that scope.

Comment: I'd wager it's supposed to be `boost::numeric::ublas::vector` and not `std::vector`. Just one more proof that `using namespace` is a bad idea.

Comment: @Angew Same answer then, but with `#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp>` ;)

Comment: I spend entirely too much time using STL, everything is std:: for me.  I also very rarely utilize 'using'.  I like explicit namespace declaration for clarity.

Comment: I added this #include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp>, still same error.

Comment: I would look further at `Y_MATRIX(A_MATRIX_ROWS,1);`  Maybe something isn't working as it should with the Y_MATRIX macro and is causing the next line to be invalid.

Comment: i checked, i removed function GPSR_BB, remaning code is working, it is with function declaration

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
vector <double> GPSR_BB(boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> &f_Y_MATRIX,
  boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> &f_A_MATRIX,
  int f_tau,
  int f_tolA){}
```

You are defining the return value type of `GPSR_BB` as `vector<double>`, but you set the function body empty. So you can't return a `vector<double>` value. You may need to write some codes inside of the function, and instantiate a `vector<double>` object, and return that object.

Comment: Even though you're right, this isn't an answer to the question, the lack of a `return` statement won't cause the behaviour the OP is seeing.

Comment: it returns vector double correctly, no problem here, thank you still